C# & EF Core : multiple entities of same type relations
I have EF Core (7.0.20) Member entity like this:
public class Member : BaseEntity
{
    public Warn FirstWarn { get; set; }
    public Warn SecondWarn { get; set; }
    public Warn ThirdWarn { get; set; }
}

BaseEntity basically has only one field - Id.
And I have a Member who can have three warns:
public class Warn : BaseEntity
{
    public Member Responsible { get; set; }
    public Member IssuedTo { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
}

I need the field IssuedTo to be connection between Member and Warn and set field Responsible manually in code.
If I just leave it like this, I get an error:

Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'Member.FirstWarn' of type 'Warn'

I tried to use NotMapped property, but it completely removes this three fields from the database.
Then I tried to customize OnModelCreating method with this code:
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>(m =>
        {
            m.HasOne(w => w.FirstWarn)
             .WithOne(m => m.IssuedTo);

            m.HasOne(w => w.SecondWarn)
             .WithOne(m => m.IssuedTo);

            m.HasOne(w => w.ThirdWarn)
             .WithOne(m => m.IssuedTo);
        });

But I got an error:

Cannot create a relationship between 'Warn.IssuedTo' and 'Member.SecondWarn' because a relationship already exists between 'Warn.IssuedTo' and 'Member.FirstWarn'


What you are trying to do is set up three one to one relationships between the same two types, which is not possible / doesn't really make sense.
What you have is a single many to one relationship. First warn, second warn and third warn would all be entries in the Warn table so it's just one relationship between warn and member.
Also please note that in order to setup the foreign key relationship properly, you should add a foreign key property to the relevant class. The Warn class should have IssuedToMemberId and ResponsibleMemberId properties storing the Ids of the related members.
You should setup a single one to many relationship e.g.
Entities:
public class Member : BaseEntity
{
    public Warn FirstWarn 
    { 
        get
        {
            return Warnings?.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }
    
    public Warn SecondWarn
    { 
        get
        {
            return Warnings?.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    public Warn ThirdWarn
    { 
        get
        {
            return Warnings?.ElementAtOrDefault(0);
        }
    }

    public virtual List<Warn> Warnings { get;set; }
}

DB Config:
modelBuilder.Entity<Member>(m =>
{
    m.HasMany(w => w.Warnings)
    .WithOne(m => m.IssuedTo)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.IssuedToMemberId); //add foreign key property to Warn class
});

See the Microsoft documentation for setting up one to many relationships in EF Core for more info.

What you are trying to do is to "bind" one end of foreign key relationship to Warn.IssuedTo property.
And you try to do it for three FKs. The reason why it does not work can be looked at from couple of perspectives:

Database perspective - one to one relationship suggests the warning will have one member, while actually it could have potentially three... imagine member with the same ID for all three warnings. Also, this will mean, that FK needs to be created multiple times for the same column, which is not allowed.

Entity Framework perspective - when it will try to fill your member navigation property for the warn, how it will be able to tell which user it should be? The one that has the warning as its first?


Only solution here is to create navigation property for each FK relationship.
